# Typescript ReferenceError: MyClass not defined, when I used MyClass inside a constructor

Tags: typescript

I have a class defined in `my_class.ts`

```
export default class MyClass {}
```

And I have another class using it inside the constructor

```
import MyClass from "./my-class.ts";
export default class MyOtherClass {
    constructor(public myClass: MyClass) {}
}
```

In my `main.ts` I got reference error when running the code (no error when compiled)

```
import MyClass from "./my-class.ts";
import MyOtherClass from "./my-other-class.ts";
const myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(new MyClass());
                                          ^^^^^^^
        ReferenceError: my_class_1 is not defined
```

And if I changed my code to

```
const myClass = new MyClass();
const myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(myClass);
```

It worked.

This happened when I upgrade TypeScript from 2.8.3 to 2.9.1.
I checked the compiled JavaScript code and they were exactly same between 2.8.3 and 2.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the root cause. This is related with some changed in TypeScript transpile module in v2.9. When I was compile and run my source code, or using `ts-node` with default options, everything works well. But when I was using `node -r ts-node/register/transpile-only main.ts`, I got this error.

Developer in TypeScript already acknowledge this issue and they said it will be fixed in v2.9.2.

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/591
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24620